# Wave-particle duality or particle-wave duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons, electrons, wave-particle-duality

Is there a difference between { a particle that acts as a wave} & { a wave that acts as a particle} ??
Ex: when u consider electrons, they have a specific mass and an inconstant velocity, but when we consider photons, they neither have a specific mass nor a changing velocity.

Comment: All elementary particles exhibit the wave particle duality. An electron has different properties than a photon and these two are different from say, a Neutrino. Having / not having mass, and having / not having a constant velocity are independent of the wave-particle character.

Comment: Don't get hung-up on word arguments. QM is expressed in mathematical symbols. Yes, we must describe those symbols in terms of words. But it's the relationships of the symbols that we should be thinking about.